# VMWare Player and multiple monitors in fullscreen

Tags: multiple-monitors, vmware-player

I'm using

- VMWare Player 4
- Windows 8 Dev Preview as guest OS
- Windows 7 as host OS

On my host OS, I have 3 physical monitors. I've set up the guest to have 2 monitors.

When I boot into the guest OS, the dual monitor support works great within the VMWare window - i.e. both monitors are shown side by side within the VMWare window.  I can set one to be Metro, the other the desktop, etc.

What I'd really like is each monitor in the guest OS to occupy a separate physical monitor, full screen.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure about VMWare Player 4, from the amount of responses in the past 3 years I would have to say no, it's not possible. However, for the sake of Google, the following should help:

It is possible under VMWare Player 7 (current version)

- Open the virtual machine
- Set to full screen
- The VMWare toolbar will now be at the top center of the screen. On the left side there should be an icon featuring two overlapping screens. A mouse over will display the "Cycle Multiple Monitors" caption.
- Click the icon